# From string fo DataSet without passing through HTML file

Tags: c#-4.0, dataset

I have a string with length no more than 4000 chars which is a valid xml. Is there a way to pass it to Dataset without creating a temporary xml file?
At the moment I do so:

```
        string validXml = TextBox1.Text;
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\tmp.xml";
        FileInfo xmlProcess = new FileInfo(path);
        using (StreamWriter sw = xmlProcess.CreateText())
        {
            sw.WriteLine(validXml);
        }

        DataSet aDataSet = new DataSet();
        aDataSet.ReadXml(reader);
```

Is there a way to skip this creating and filling the tmp.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(validXml));
DataSet aDataSet = new DataSet();
aDataSet.ReadXml(reader);
```